# Is it possible to make REST API calls in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-storage

I'm new to Snowflake and I'm not so strong in using SQL but my question is if it is possible to perform a (POST) request from Snowflake to the Azure Blob Service REST API in order to obtain a User Delegation Key. Can this be easily done?
In Snowflakes documentation I read about external functions which may could be used to execute some kind of script for acquiring a User Delegation Key but it seems to be a hassle to set this all up (see https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-creating-azure.html)

If not, do you by any chance have an idea on how to design a managable process in order to obtain access to an Azure Blob Storage via Azure AD user credentials?

Comment: Access to the Azure Blob storage from Snowflake can be achieved either using the SAS token route or using the Storage Integration. The details for it are here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html 

But, as such there are no specific REST API to do the operations that can be used.

Comment: We came across the proposed options by Snowflake regarding Azure but, unfortunately, we don't find them viable for us. That is because we do not see a practicable way to handle the SAS tokens that are generated through the storage account keys in the case that SAS tokens are compromised.

Comment: Yes, that is something of a limitation with the way ADF has designed the connection with SF.